# Getting the individual digits of a number

Tags: java, performance, strings, comparative-review

**Approach 1:**

Repeated division-modulus operations:

```
long num = 123456789;
int count = 0;
while(num > 0)
{
 int digit = num % 10;
 if(digit == 1)
  count ++;
 num /= 10;
}
```

**Approach 2:**

Convert it into an `String` and get the characters at the position:

```
long num = 123456789;
int count = 0;
String s = String.valueOf(num);
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
 char ch = s.charAt(i);
 if(ch == '1')
    count ++;
}
```

The second operation doesn't need to get the remainder and the quotient each time. A `charAt()` method can be enough.

Which approach is considered to be better and why?

Consider taking the input from the console.

1st Case:

```
long num = scanner.nextLong();
```

2nd Case:

```
String s = scanner.nextLine();
```

Here there would be no overhead on converting the `number` to `string`.

Also let us assume it is for positive numbers.

Comment: Welcome to CR! In what context will this be used for?

Comment: Knowledge gaining context!

Comment: As in you're just interested to count the number of `1`s? Would this be used in a method with the signature `private static int countOccurrence(int number, int searchFor)`?

Comment: @h.j.k. Counting numbers is just an example. I wanted to know which would be better to get the individual digits.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a third approach that extends the conversion-to-string approach: conversion to `List` of `Character`

The benefits of this is that you can utilise Java 8 collection stream feature to perform filtering, aggregation and other functions on the elements.

for instance, your example can be expressed as such (edited following @h.j.k's comment):

```
    long num = 123456789;
    String s = String.valueOf(num);
    long count = s.chars()
            .mapToObj(i -> (char)i)
            .filter(ch -> ch.equals('1'))
            .count();
```

Comment: Wells, if you really want to go down this way, then there's [`String.chars()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--) that will give you an `IntStream` directly.

Answer (score 1):

This method below allows you to get a specific number from a int value based on a specific index

```
    public static int getSpecificNum(int number, int index) {
    int numOfDigits = 0;
    int pow = 1, test = 0, counter = 0;
```

//gets the number of digits

```
    while (test != number) {// once the full int is retrieved
        counter++;//<-digit counter
        pow *= 10;
        test = number % pow;//go through the entire int
    }
```

// number of digits are found, reset everything

```
    numOfDigits = counter;
    counter = 0;
    pow = 1;
    test = 0;
```

// now count until the index

```
    while (counter != (numOfDigits - index)) {// this is numOfDigits was needed
        counter++;
        pow *= 10;
        test = number % pow;// same thing

    }
```

// exp = finding the power of 10

```
    int exp = numOfDigits - (index + 1);
    exp = (int) Math.pow(10, exp);
    return test / exp;//divide and conquer  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the length of the number you don't need an array. Just using log base 10 will get you the number of places the number has so,

```
long num = 123456789;
int length = (int) Math.log10(num); //should make the length 9
```

Now to get a specific number it's

```
public int getNthDigit(int number, int base, int n) {    
    return (int) ((number / Math.pow(base, n - 1)) % base);
}
```

If you enter `getNthDigit(num,10,8);` then it will return 2.

Comment: The approach to find the length of a number by taking log base 10 is incorrect.

`This does not work always. For example: 
If num is 10, your code will return 1
If num is 100, your code will return 2
If num is 1000, your code will return 3

Similarly, for other numbers (example 2), it will not return the length as 1.
Math.log10(2) = 0.3010299956639812
and casting it to int will give 0`

Answer (score 0):

Corner failure

`while(num > 0) { ...}` fails to get the right count when `long num = 0;` and the `digit` sought is 0.  `count` result is 0.  I'd expect 1.

Failure when `num < 0` as `int digit = num % 10;` will result in a negative value.

---

Oops now see in the end: "Also let us assume it is for positive numbers."  Making answer wiki as a reference.

Too bad as it is not difficult to make the code work for all `int`.